# Creating a model association with multiple field key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem about creating a relation between two tables, the table structure between products and favorites,

the table products consist of id, name, code, sub_code, size. And favorites table consist of id, code, sub_code, user_id.

the problem why i'm not using id as association is, when there are new products, the whole products table will be truncated and new product list will be imported. So using id as association will not work perfectly.

Is there a way how to make an association between those tables using code and sub_code as relation?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to
you could do something like:

```
belongs_to :product, ->(){where("products.sub_code=favorites.sub_code")}, foreign_key: :code, primary_key: :code
```

Don't forget to add indexes to all those fields you're building relations on.